# macos unable to find SDL2/SDL.h file even with compiler args

Tags: c++, macos, sdl

I am working on a chip8 emulator and when implementing the graphics, I am getting an error that states SDL2/SDL.h file not found

using an m1 mac vscode, I have the SDL2.framework folder in Library/Frameworks, and the makefile is as follows

```
CXX := g++ 
CXXFLAGS := -std=c++14 -Wall -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers 
LDFLAGS := -F/Library/Frameworks -framework SDL2 

TARGET := chip8_emulator

SRCS := chip8.cpp graphics.cpp
OBJS := $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $<

clean:
    rm -f $(TARGET) $(OBJS)
```

here is the graphics.hpp file for reference

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

class graphics
{
private:
    int screen_width;
    int screen_height;
    int chip8_width;
    int chip8_height;

    SDL_Window *window;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer;
    SDL_Texture *texture;

public:
    graphics(int, int);
    bool init_Screen();
    void clear_screen();
    void update_screen(uint32_t *);
    void destroy_screen();
};
```

as you may guess, any function requiring the SDL library is throwing an undefined error

Most common solutions state that the -F flag in the makefile should resolve the issue, as I believe it is how the folders are structured on macs, there is no SDL2 folder. If i remove SDL2 and just #include<SDL.h>, i am getting the same error as well.

Comment: This kind of problem is best solved by looking at the files you have on your drive. Does `/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers/SDL2/SDL.h` exist? I believe this is the path of the header you are telling your compiler to look for. If that file does not exist where is the `SDL.h` file?

Comment: Is it installed in the system directory `/Library` or your home directory which would be `~/Library`? How did you install SDL2?

Comment: It is in the system directory, @drescherjm's comment gave me the idea to just create the SDL2 folder in the headers subdirectory, compiler is able to find the files now

Comment: So wait, it had `SDL.h` directly, and you moved it to `SDL2/SDL.h` just to have a nice path?

Answer (score 1):

When you install `sdl2` it also installs `sdl2-config`.

You can run this to get the extra flags you need:

Add the following to your Makefile:

```
LDFLAGS  :=$(shell sdl2-config --libs)
CXXFLAGS :=$(shell sdl2-config --cflags)
```